# Cannot access certain reddit data through scrapy shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am very new to scrapy and am trying to scrape posts on reddit. To help, I have accessed the scrapy shell and am trying to dig out the posts. The page I am using is https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/6a4ie8/philippines_senator_tells_un_reports_of_drug_war/

I have viewed the source and have found the following data I want to access:

"class="usertext-body may-blank-within md-container ">< div class="md" >< p >It seems to me that the senator was using the term "alternative facts" the opposite way Conway used them. He used them to discred e.t.c"

Why when I type in response.xpath('//div[@class="md"]).extract() I get an empty array. Furthermore I get empty arrays when trying to access a lot of the data on this page through the shell.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using both `response.css` and `response.xpath`, avoid using `form` id as it seems to change:

```
>>> response.css('div.entry form div.usertext-body div.md p ::text').extract_first()
'It seems to me that the senator was using the term "alternative facts" the opposite way Conway used them. He used them to discredit the interpretation of said "facts" as lies, insisting that many of the homicides being counted as extra-judicial killings were just regular homicides.'
>>> 
>>> response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'entry')]/form/div/div/p[1]/text()").extract_first()
'It seems to me that the senator was using the term "alternative facts" the opposite way Conway used them. He used them to discredit the interpretation of said "facts" as lies, insisting that many of the homicides being counted as extra-judicial killings were just regular homicides.'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked for me. It seems I thought I knew xpath more than I do. Do you know why using //div[@class='md'] doesn't work?

Comment: if you run `//div[@class='md']` in `shell`, you would get the result you were expecting along with `html tags` and other comments, you need to then filter out from the result, use `text()` to remove tags.  i just pin pointed my xpath to the result you were expecting.

Comment: ah yes. I ran into an issue because I used double quotes: response.xpath('//div[@class="md"]'). Eternally grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to the text of every post, you can use this xpath:

`response.xpath('//form[contains(@id, "form-t1")]//div//div//p/text()').extract()`.

You can learn more about xpaths here: [Scrapy Selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/topics/selectors.html)

Finally, here is a very usefull tool if you want to test xpaths: [Videlibri](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi). In the left textarea you paste the HTML you want to parse, in the right one you paste your xpath. You now can easilly test your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks so much for your help. When I enter response.xpath('//*[@id="form-t1_dhbsy4cbgx"]/div/div//p') I still get an empty array

Comment: I updated my answer, the xpath didn't work because the site generates new tag ids every time you load the page.